# Backup strategy for non-rooted phone

Tags: adb, backup

With apologies for my naivete:

I want, insofar as possible, to periodically back up the data on my non-rooted Samsung Galaxy S8.  To this end I do two things:

1)  I periodically do adb backups with the command

> adb backup -all -apk -shared -f backupfile

2)  I mount my phone as a network drive on my Windows machine, where I use robocopy to maintain mirrors of the directories /sdcard and /storage/0000-0000.  These mirrors are updated nightly via a script containing the commands

> robocopy z:\sdcard d:\phone /s /z /zb /mir /xx /xo /fft  /r:0 /w:0 /min:10
>
> robocopy z:\storage\0000-0000 d:\phone /s /z /zb /mir /xx /xo /xd mp3s /fft /r:0 /w:0 /min:10

Thanks to Izzy's very helpful answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/196609/location-of-files-main-storage-versus-sd-card), I am aware that some apps store data in directories such as /data/data that are not accessible to me without root access, and also that some apps might have opted out of making their data accessible to the adb backup.

**Question 1:**  To clarify:  Is the adb backup (at least potentially) capturing at least some data beyond what I'm able to capture in my mirrors?

**Question 2:**  Is the adb backup restricted to data that has been created by apps?  For example, if I've manually copied a file from my computer to my phone's SD card, is that file included in the adb backup?

**Question 3:**  Does any of the above strike you as insane, and if so, what strategy would be saner (short of rooting, which I prefer to avoid)?

Comment: Most of your questions are already answered on our site. May I suggest you take a look into our [backup tag-wiki](/tags/backup/info) and [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](/q/28296/16575)?

Comment: > "mount my phone as a network drive" Could you please share how you achieved this?
I have been googling, but haven't yet stumbled on the correct incantation.
I'm not sure what directory to point Powershell, since it doesn't seem to be able to see the phone.

Comment: I did this long ago, and this is from memory, so I can't guarantee it's accurate.  But:  Since you mention Powershell, I assume you are using Windows.  Step I:  install WebDavServer on your phone from the App store.  Step II: Start the webdav server, and it will tell you your phone's IP address.  Step III:  From left column of Windows file manager, right-click "This PC" and choose "Add a Network Drive".  This will let you enter your phone's IP address and assign it a drive letter.  With the WebDav server turned on in your phone, the computer will usually see the phone as a drive with the (CTD)

Comment: (CTD) assigned letter.  Sometimes (apparently randomly) the computer fails to see the phone, in which case you can look in the left column of File Manager, look for the network drive you created and click it a couple of times or something until the computer figures out what you're trying to do.  Now you can just type "Z:" (or whatever letter you assigned) in your command window and use your phone as a hard drive.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that - I will give WebDavServer app a try!

Comment: @m1m1k :  Just in case this trips you up:  You need to choose between "map network drive" and "add network location" from the file manager dropdown.  I am pretty sure you want the former and very sure that you need to make the right choice.